# How to use Redux' useSelector and useDispatch hooks with PropTypes

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, react-proptypes

In React class components with `mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps` every incoming state/dispatch prop is easy to type check with PropTypes.

When rewriting `mapStateToProps -> useSelector`, and `mapDispatchToProps -> useDispatch` I no longer see any logical place to do proptype checking. Unless I manually check proptypes with `PropTypes.checkPropTypes()`.

I guess it's more important to do proptype checks of props from parent components than from Redux, but I would still like to know if anyone has a good solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you call `connect()` in your component, what you're doing is creating an HOC or Higher Order Component. This component "wraps" in which you call `connect()`. The HOC then passes props to the wrapped component as a `props` object.

The members of this object can in-turn be type-checked by a package like `prop-types`. The problem here is that when using hooks, you're no longer wrapping the component at all. You're deriving state right there in the function body as the function runs. This means that the value you are using is no longer a "prop".

Unfortunately, there is no convenient way to automatically type-check values in JavaScript. One could add TypeScript or Flow, but that brings type-checking for *every* variable/function return in the entire file. Perhaps this is what you want, but it adds a great deal of overhead.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using PropTypes.checkPropTypes for useSelector hook. And it works for me.

```
const { title, loggedIn } = withPropsValidation(
 useSelector(state => ({
   title: state.title, 
   loggedIn: state.loggedIn
})))

const withPropsValidation = props => {
  PropTypes.checkPropTypes(propTypes, props, 'prop', '')
  return props
}

const propTypes = {
  title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  loggedIn: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
}
```

https://github.com/facebook/prop-types#proptypescheckproptypes